# The ASP UpdatePanel doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to update a part of my aspx page by using UpdatePanel but it doesn't work

here is a part of aspx page code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>                                
           <asp:CheckBox ID="cb1" name="cb1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="cb_test_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" /><label for="cb1"><%=DateTime.Now %></label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is a part of code behind:

```
protected void cb_test_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
    }
```

When i try to click on the checkbox no think happens into to TextBox.

NB: In the browser consol i have :

```
Error: Sys. WebForms. PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: impossible to analyze the message received from the waiter(server). This error can have several possible causes: answer modified by calls(appeals) to Response. Write (), leak out of answer, HttpModules or activation of track of the waiter(server). Details: error of analysis near '
```

Comment: Try setting ChildrenAsTriggers="True" on the UpdatePanel

Comment: Is the cb_test_CheckedChanged call being hit?

Comment: @DarrenGourley it did it but it still not working

Comment: @Justin when i debug , It reaches the method cb_test_CheckedChanged

Comment: @TinyOS I've just copied and pasted your code in to a default webapplication and it worked. Do you have any code in your prerender that sets the textbox back to empty? (Just a punt in the dark)

Comment: I don't have any code whitch make textbox back to empty

Comment: What is in the `Page_Load` event?

Comment: I changed the stucture of my code as shown above , i edited the code

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors in the browser console?

Comment: @Darren Gourely i have this in browser consol:

Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Impossible d'analyser le message reçu du serveur. Cette erreur peut avoir plusieurs causes possibles : réponse modifiée par des appels à Response.Write(), filtres de réponse, HttpModules ou activation de trace du serveur.

Détails : Erreur d'analyse à proximité de '

Comment: in english i can say :

Error: Sys. WebForms. PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: impossible to analyze the message received from the waiter(server). This error can have several possible causes: answer modified by calls(appeals) to Response. Write (), leak out of answer, HttpModules or activation of track of the waiter(server).

Details: error of analysis near '

Comment: Ok, do you have any other code that would be executed (in, but not limited to, page init, load, prerender) that makes a Response.write() or server.execute call?

Comment: No i have juste Jquery  to do some attractive interactions on menu

Comment: Set a breakpoint on cb_test_CheckedChanged and step through the rest of the request. Make sure it exits normally and you don't come across any Response.Write(). Also, was there any more information on your javascript error message in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you put the Checkbox outside the update panel it will work, also remove UpdatePanel1.Update(); from codebehind

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb1" name="cb1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="cb_test_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" /><label for="cb1">Example</label>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ContentTemplate>            
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="bidon" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="cb1" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


        protected void cb_test_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bidon.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: if i make Checkbox outside the update panel and i remove UpdatePanel.1.Update() how i wan that juste the UpdatePanel be refreshed only

Comment: when you check or uncheck the checkbox it will only refresh the updatepanel, you tried it?

Comment: This will perform a full page postback. You would need to add an asyncpostbacktrigger to the UpdatePanel to make this work. You also won't be able to use UpdatePanel1.Update() if the UpdatePanel is not Conditional UpdateMode.

Comment: ok, I added an AsyncPostBackTrigger  as Darren said, it will no longer perform a full postback

Comment: @NorbertoEscobar i did like what you wrote but i still not working and when i show the browser consol i have the error above (edited poste)

Comment: I see it working but can't tell why it isn't working for you